# Navigate toggle scroll down more than the beginning of the section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am creating my first project in Bootstrap and when I click on some link in navbar-toggle it throws me a little down from the beginning of the section, I tried to search in every way what is making it have this result but I can't find it. Does anyone give me a light?

Link to my project: https://clube.com.br/new/

Comment: Where is your navbar toggle?

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the same for you

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
});

<a href="#bottom" id="top">Click to scroll down</a>

<div id="star">&star;</div>

<a href="#top" id="bottom">Click to scroll up</a>
```

Please check this link it has the same example

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2